# Remove the display flex property from the MuiCollapse-wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to remove the display flex property from the `MuiCollapse-wrapper`,
so I researched and found the wrapper rule name in this link https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/

I couldn't overwrite with this class name wrapper, I am trying to remove display flex from this class `MuiCollapse-wrapper`. Can you tell me how to fix it?

Code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-i00qt

```or-tag-here
wrapper: {
    display: "inherit !important"
  }

  <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>

          <FormControl
            style={{
              width: "100%"
            }}
            component="fieldset"
            className={classes.formControl}
          >
            <li>
              Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add saffron
              and set aside for 10 minutes{" "}
            </li>
            <li>
              Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet
              over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook,
              stirring occasionally until lightly browned, 6 to 8 minutes.
              Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken
              and chorizo in the pan
            </li>
          </FormControl>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `withStyle` option? That will allow you to overwrite the component default style: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro hey can you update in my code sandbox so confusing :(

Comment: hey it worked thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hey below code changes fixed the issue, updated my sandbox too https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-i00qt

```
alignment: {
    display: "inherit !important"
  }

<Collapse
        classes={{
          wrapper: classes.alignment
        }}
        in={expanded}
        timeout="auto"
        unmountOnExit
      >
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, I had a hard time understanding the same documentation.